# How can you change category position per store view

Tags: magento

Has anyone been able to change the position of categories per store view in Magento? I haven't looked yet at the code on how the position gets set, but I know you set the position through the admin site with the category tree. You currently out of the box can't change this tree for different websites or store views. I tried changing the attributes is_global column in the database to the store view number, but that didn't work when I tried changing it per store view. I am assuming the code on the backend doesn't have the logic to look for what store view it is and assign it since they have it marked as global and don't give you the option to change it.

I have two websites that have similar hierarchies and it is going to make sense to use the same root catalog rather then duplicating so much of the tree and having to assign the products to both. Ideally being able to change the position through the admin would be best so that in the future the client can move a category without having to touch any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible.

Category entity has attribute 'position' which is actually static (it means that the attribute is in the main catalog_category_entity table). Also we have 'path' column in the main table for defining categories relation.

This two column is the base for category position.

About attributes: Did you tried to change values per attribute in the catalog_eav_attribute? Column 'position' in this table used for layered navigation on the frontend (but this attribute is deprecated).

So, on my point of view only with customization we can change this logic.

Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I found, thanks for the answer. I didn't think about the attribute position being for the layered nav totally forgot about that. I don't think it is worth it for us to try and change this functionality we are going to go with another approach